# Java console readPassword() returns nonsense characters

Tags: java, io, passwords

Am having a ridiculous difficulty with Java's Console object, and particularly the `readPassword()` method.

I have the current code to read in a password, twice, and loop until the two passwords are the same:

```
do {
    dbPasswordOne = userInput.readPassword("Enter a password for the bookstall: ");
    System.out.println(dbPasswordOne.toString());
    dbPasswordTwo = userInput.readPassword("Re-enter the password: ");
    System.out.println(dbPasswordTwo.toString());
} while (!Arrays.equals(dbPasswordOne, dbPasswordTwo));
```

To my eye, this should work fine (the printing is there simply for debugging purposes. However, this is the output I get in a Linux terminal:

```
Enter a password for the bookstall: 
[C@9e4acce
Re-enter the password: 
[C@40d0d75
```

It's always the same two nonsense strings every time I run it, regardless of what I've input. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What are the types for "dbPasswordOne and dbPasswordTwo?  It looks like you're trying to print an object (not a string).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are calling `toString()` on a `char[]`. That autoboxes the `char[]` and the string you are seeing is its reference name. You have to convert your `char[]` into a `String`.

Try `System.out.println(new String(dbPasswordOne));`

Comment: How did you know it was a `char[]`?  Does something in the `toString()` return tell you?

Comment: new String() is not needed, furthermore autoboxing has nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `dbPasswordTwo.toString()` `toString()` as this prints out the reference name. just remove `toString()`.

`PrintWriter` which is `System.out` has a `println(char[])` method, which is called then. this prints out every character, and does not call the `toString()` method implicit.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a complete example, adapted from the "Console.readPassword()" example I suspect you're probably using:

```
/*
 * REFERENCE:
 * http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0120__Development/Readpasswordfromconsole.htm
 *
 * SAMPLE OUTPUT:
 * Enter your login: abc
 * Enter your old password:
 * You entered: def...
 */
import java.io.Console;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class X {

  public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {

    Console c = System.console();
    if (c == null) {
      System.err.println("No console.");
      System.exit(1);
    }

    String login = c.readLine("Enter your login: ");
    char[] oldPassword = c.readPassword("Enter your old password: ");

    String sPassword = new String(oldPassword);
    System.out.println ("You entered: " + sPassword + "...");
  }
}
```

Note the line `String sPassword = new String(oldPassword);`.  This converts a char[] array into a printable string.

'Hope that helps!

Comment: Security warning: the reason it's in a char array is to be able to blank it after you use it. If, as you've done here, you stick it in a String, you [expose it to memory sniffing for a potentially unlimited amount of time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3451335). Note that the originals examples don't do that, at [your link](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0120__Development/Readpasswordfromconsole.htm) and at the [Oracle Java tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/cl.html) ([code](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/examples/Password.java)).

Comment: Why are we echoing the user's password to the screen? Did the user consent to this? The other half of the point of readPassword is that it _doesn't_ get echoed.